# Redirect old products product.php links to home page in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am using a new eCommerce platform and I am looking for a way to make all old product.php? links redirect to the new homepage

For example in Google Webmasters it is finding these 2 links:

```
/product.php?productid=11012&cat=445&page=1
/product.php?productid=10348&cat=0&page=1
```

I want to redirect any URLs that look this to the home page.

Right now I have the following in the .htaccess file

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /product\.php([?#][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^product\.php http://www.mysite.co.uk/ [L,R=301]
```

However this makes the link redirect from `/product.php?productid=11012&cat=445&page=1` to `?productid=11012&cat=445&page=1` instead of redirecting to the homepage.

Comment: Please respond with an [appropriate error page](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-10.4.11), I hate it when you’re just getting redirected to the home page without any note.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `?` to the target URL to drop current/existing query string:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /product\.php([?#][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^product\.php http://www.mysite.co.uk/? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Sorry did not get back to you this ended up working perfectly. Thanks for your help